# Large amounts of Data into sheet using array

Tags: arrays, excel, jagged-arrays

I am downloading 43 stock symbols historical pricing into excel 2013.  my code uses a 2d array which is then transposed and inserted into a sheet.  It works fine, until I try and download pricing going back to 1990 for the 43 symobls.  It seems that once the second dimension of the array gets over a certain amount the cell value turns to #N/A as some point down column one.  Any thoughts on a jagged array (nested array) but how would I loop through to make the output range I need?  thanks for all the suggestions.

> RERFX RFNCX   RWICX   SASMX   SGRKX   SGRKX   SMGIX   TRSGX   VETAX   VIMAX   VINIX   VIPSX   VSCAX   WACPX   WAPAX   WASAX
>   5/15/2002   6/4/2002    6/6/2002    1/1/2001    8/30/2002   8/30/2002   1/1/2001    1/1/2001    5/5/2000    11/12/2001  1/1/2001    6/29/2000   1/1/2001    1/1/2001    5/21/2012   5/21/2012

These are the symbols and the dates. I created a range for all the symbols and then created the start dates by making ranges out of the symbols themselves.

```
Sub GetDailyReturnsTest()
Dim URL As String, today As String, http As Object, csv As String, temp() As String
Dim txt As String, r As Integer, a As Single, b As String, s As Double, ticker As Variant, icountSymbol As Integer, sTicker As String
Dim iSymbol As Integer, dateParams As String, t As Double, sym As range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False



Set ticker = Application.[fundsymbols]
icountSymbol = ticker.Count

ReDim temp(8, 0)

today = Date
For Each sym In ticker
dateParams = "&a=" & Month(range(sym)) - 1 & "&b=" & Day(range(sym)) & "&c=" & Year(range(sym)) & "&d=" & Month(Now) & "&e=" & Day(Now) & "&f=" & Year(Now)





sTicker = ticker(1, iSymbol)

URL = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & sTicker & dateParams & "g=d&ignore=.csv"


On Error Resume Next

Set http = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
http.Open "get", URL, False
http.send
csv = http.ResponseText
r = 0
txt = ""
For a = 1 To Len(csv)
b = Mid(csv, a, 1)
If b = "," Then
    temp(r, UBound(temp, 2)) = txt
    r = r + 1
    txt = ""
ElseIf b = Chr(10) Then
temp(r, UBound(temp, 2)) = txt
r = r + 1
txt = sTicker
temp(r, UBound(temp, 2)) = txt
ReDim Preserve temp(UBound(temp, 1), UBound(temp, 2) + 1)
txt = ""
r = 0
Else
    txt = txt & b
End If
Next a
Next sym
Worksheets("FundsHistoricalPricing").Activate
On Error Resume Next


With ActiveSheet.Cells
.ClearContents
.ClearFormats
End With

range("a2").Resize(UBound(temp, 2) + 1, UBound(temp, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(temp)
end sub
```

Comment: We'll need to see the code.

Comment: If you add a break in, does the array have the correct data?

Comment: yes if you look in the array all the data is there.  The problem seems to happen with the transpose part of the code.